# Is an iPhone being peripheral and central with connecting to several peripheral iPhones one after another doable?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

My app needs to detect other iPhones and connect to all of them one at a time quickly (Those iPhones also have the same functionality). So I implemented both peripheral and central. I only try connecting to another phone if:

```
if (![_discoveredPeripheral isConnected] && [[UIDevice currentDevice] name] < [advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataLocalName"])
```

(I advertise the name of the device to avoid both devices to connect to each other at the same time)

It works correctly, but after a few minutes I get this error:

```
[1622:1103] CoreBluetooth[ERROR] XPC connection interrupted, resetting
```

Is the problem in my algorithm of connecting? Or is it not doable to be a peripheral and connect as a central at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I was also working with the same kind of application. As I understand you are trying to use same device for the central as well as peripheral application .You cannot do this . Because what I have observe is peripheral application is only can be detected when it is in foreground and in same device you cant run the two program in the foreground at a time . So you need to install the central and peripheral application in two separate devices .

Comment: They aren't two different apps. The same controller implements both and it works without connecting. But once I connect, the app crashes after a while.

Comment: actually you can implement both central and peripheral in a single application . But only one mode  will work at a time .

Comment: That's what I did. But for both to work do I have to stopAdvertising when I startScanning and stopScan when I startAdvertising?

Comment: have look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html this is what you wanted .

Comment: I've seen that. This is not what I want. I need the all the iPhones to be centrals and peripherals at the same time without any user interacting with the phone in order to exchange information.